# How to format a label based on its successor in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector)

Is there any way to format an element based on its successor? 
Example:

```
<label for="myelement">My Label</label>
<input type="text" name="test" id="myelement" />

<label for="different">Another Label</label>
<input type="radio" name="anothertest" id="different" value="yes" />
```

Now I'm formatting `label` with CSS like this:

```
label { display: block; }
```

It's obvious now, that this affects the styling of all `label` elements. But I'd like to avoid this when an `input` element of `type=radio` is following the `label`. Is there any way to achieve this in CSS **without** using any `class` or `id` element?

Comment: No not with css but with javascript there is.

Comment: @BoltClock If I'm understanding the sibling selector correctly it just does the opposite of what I'm talking about. I don't want to style the `input` but the `<label for="different">` differently to the other `label`s.

Comment: @Damien: It's talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. css only allows you to select based on the predecessor using +